# Aging Objects in a Collection

Tags: java, collections, queue, priority-queue, cache-expiration

I want to be able to age objects in a Collection.

For example I could put strings in a HashSet.

1. I would like timestamps associated of when the String was put in the HashSet.
2. I would like String older than say time X to be dropped from the HashSet.
3. I would like to be able to say "touch" a string and update the time to when it was inserted in the Collection.

So I can accomplish this by keeping track of each String and then running a house cleaning Thread and purging String from the Collection if it is older than a certain time quantum.

However I am looking for:

1. Either a Clever way to do this.
2. An existing open-source java component which accomplishes this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you need a cache. Either try [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) (see [*Caches Explained*](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)) from Guava or [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/).

Answer (score 5):

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) caches meet all your requirements and more! See [Caches Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: +1 for guava! did not think about it immediately

Answer (score 1):

I would use [JCS](http://commons.apache.org/jcs/), really like the Guava idea though @sjr

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create your own Collection class (for the house cleaning tasks) that's backed by a `HashMap<String, Date>` ?